# Laravel 5 Nginx redirects to 404

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, nginx-location

My Laravel 5 website redirects to 404. It is installed in a folder.

It is using Laravel 5.6 and Nginx 1.12.1

It is redirecting to 404 instead of my project. Planning to deploy multiple sites.

https://example.com/staging/project/ -> Redirects to 404 instead of opening the page.

Find nginx config

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /var/www/example;
    index   index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    location ^~ /staging/project {
      alias /var/www/example/staging/project/public;
      index index.php
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args @laravel1;

    location ~ \.php {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
  }

   location @laravel1 {
       rewrite /staging/project/(.*)$ /staging/project/index.php?/$1 last;
   }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Comment: did you restart the nginx?

Comment: Yes more than 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one thing wrong here which i think you need to change, you are almost there.

Change

```
root         /var/www/example;
```

To

```
root         /var/www/example/public;
```

Also always restart Nginx everytime you change the xxx.conf file.

```
Sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: My root is having some other php app so cant add public in root path

Comment: When you install Laravel, you will see the structure and there is public folder/directory in the installation, you have to point to that in your nginx conf root. Other than that your framework will never read it's entry point index.php and it will always spit 404 page by Nginx.